# Gatsby-node.js : Cannot read property 'allMarkdownRemark' of undefined

Tags: gatsby

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'allMarkdownRemark' of undefined

```
  138 |         const categorySet = new Set()
  139 | 
> 140 |         result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(edge => {
      |                     ^
  141 |           if (edge.node.frontmatter.tags) {
  142 |             edge.node.frontmatter.tags.forEach(tag => {
  143 |               tagSet.add(tag)
```

The query is the following :

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogQuery {
    posts: allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 2000
      sort: { fields: [fields___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { template: { eq: "post" } } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
            date
          }
          excerpt(pruneLength: 180)
          timeToRead
          frontmatter {
            title
            tags
            categories
            thumbnail {
              childImageSharp {
                fixed(width: 50, height: 50) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                }
              }
            }
            date
            template
          }
        }
      }
    }
    categories: allMarkdownRemark(limit: 2000) {
      group(field: frontmatter___categories) {
        fieldValue
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
```

Trying to figure out the error here & Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please show your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general to debug these situations just log the object and see whats missing

```
console.log(result.data);
```

In your graphql query

```
posts: allMarkdownRemark(
```

This means you will access `allMarkdownRemark` as `posts`. This is some kind of renaming the variables.

use this to make it work

```
result.data.posts.edges.forEach
```